# Is there a way to tell what price a stock will be before the market opens?

Tags: stock-markets, price, economics, price-theory

I was reading about an [Atlassian security vulnerability](https://www.zdnet.com/article/us-cybercom-says-mass-exploitation-of-atlassian-confluence-vulnerability-ongoing-and-expected-to-accelerate/) and was curious as to the effects on its stock price. Surprisingly, its stock price over the past 5 days was ***up** 6.83%*!? But I checked and [Monday was a public holiday in the US](https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/is-the-stock-market-closed-on-labor-day-2021-2021-09-05) and therefore the NASDAQ wasn't trading, hence the [price](https://www.google.com/search?q=atlassian+stock+price) is Friday's price, as indicated by the date on the chart (Sept 3rd):

[image]

So, purely out of curiosity, I wonder: other than reading expert opinion, is there any way to estimate, preferably through data and inference, what a stock price will be when a market isn't open? Or more precisely, what a stock price will be when the market does eventually open?

Note: I considered trying to infer what a stock is selling for [privately](https://www.nasdaq.com/solutions/private-company-solutions) (off market) in transactions close to the time of the market opening. But I'm not sure if such transactions occur frequently enough, nor whether the public can actually access the prices of these trades (since they occur off-market and possibly under confidential arrangements).

Answer (score 2):

If the stock is traded internationally, you might have a look on exchanges which might be open.

Answer (score 1):

The price of a stock is a function of buying pressure versus selling pressure.  More buying pressure than selling pressure and price rises (and vice versa).

There is no way to know what the above will be or to infer at what price a stock will open on the next trading day since present order size cannot be known nor how much size will come in at the open (or in the pre-market should it be active then).